# Using a_pkg cmake extras in b_pkg cmake extras

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a situation where I want to use CMake macros defined in `a_pkg` cmake extras (defined via `CFG_EXTRAS`) in `b_pkg`'s cmake extras.

For this, in `b_pkg` I define a `buildtool_export_depend` on `a_pkg`. If I then try to build `c_pkg` with an `buildtool_depend` on `b_pkg`, it fails, since while trying to load the cmake extras from `b_pkg` the macro from `a_pkg`'s extras is not found.

It makes sense why this would happen, since nowhere does anyone call `find_package` on `a_pkg`. But what is the correct way to deal with this?

Does it make sense to manually call `find_package(a_pkg REQUIRED)` in `b_pkg`'s cmake extras file, or should there be another mechanism? Note that I do not `buildtool_depend` or `build_depend` on `a_pkg` in `b_pkg`, and therefore also don't call `find_package(catkin ...)` with `a_pkg` in the component list.

Here are the example packages: https://github.com/NikolausDemmel/test_cmake_extras

Note: Try the example package with `catkin_make`, since `catkin build` seems to have an issue with `buildtool_export_depend`, see https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/304

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228982/using-a_pkg-cmake-extras-in-b_pkg-cmake-extras/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your description, I'd say you need to `buildtool_export_depend` on `a_pkg` in `b_pkg`'s `package.xml` (as you appear to already have done) and you need `find_package(a_pkg REQUIRED)` in the extras file of `b_pkg` before you use something from it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2016-03-14**:
Would this be the place to add according documentation? https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/howto/format2/installing_cmake.rst

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-16**:
Sorry, didn't see this comment right off. I guess that would be as good of a place as any to put a note about this pattern. The other option would be to describe the pattern here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt